# Parsing into a set using boost spirit x3

Tags: c++, parsing, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am interested in if there is a way to parse into a set using boost spirit x3. the background is I have a string of tokens, each token represents a enum value, now i want to create a parser which parses if every every token is at most once in the string, it would be a charm if I could get all the parsed tokens into a `std::set` while parsing. 
To get the enums back from the parsed string I am using a symbol_table:

```
enum class foo{bar, baz, bla, huh};

    struct enum_table : x3::symbols<foo> {
        enum_table() {
            add("bar", foo::bar)
                    ("baz", foo::baz)
                    ("huh", foo::huh);
        }
    } const enum_parser;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am interested in if there is a way to parse into a set using boost spirit x3.

Spirit can parse into `std::set<>` out of the box (at least as of Boost 1.61.0), so the following already works with the types you've shown:

```
std::set<foo> foos;
x3::phrase_parse(
    input.begin(), input.end(),
    +enum_parser,
    x3::space,
    foos
);
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NhU7eJwKEgsKmLla)</kbd>

To get your parser to fail upon encountering duplicates, this is most easily accomplished with [semantic actions](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/tutorials/semantic_actions.html):

```
std::set<foo> foos;
auto insert_foo_or_fail = [&foos](auto& ctx) {
    _pass(ctx) = foos.insert(_attr(ctx)).second;
};
x3::phrase_parse(
    input.begin(), input.end(),
    +x3::omit[enum_parser[insert_foo_or_fail]],
    x3::space
);
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Qojhsdy6vDamHwZx)</kbd>

Comment: oh wow didnt knew it can parse into a set out of the box. thanks for the trick with the semantic action

Comment: this doesnt work with boost version 1.60.0 I am getting an error: `»class std::set<foo>« has no member named »push_back«` so this realy works since with boost version 1.61.0